# Lost passport after filing Dutch visa application

Tags: working-visas, netherlands, passport

I just got a job offer in the Netherlands, meaning that I need to get a TEV (entry visa), and an MVV afterwards (residence authorization). I started the process for the TEV with a passport number that I currently don't have with me anymore, meaning that I just lost it. It didn't have any relevant visas. Could I just get a new passport and update the application? Or do I need to start a new application from scratch using the new passport?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:dutch-citizens] tag because this question does not apply to Dutch citizens.  You've also misunderstood the terminology. TEV ("toegang en verblijf," meaning "entry and residence") is a single application for both a temporary-residence-permit-plus-visa, called the MVV ("machtiging tot voorlopig verblijf," meaning "permit for temporary residence"), and the subsequent residence permit that will replace it.  It used to be necessary to apply for these separately.  But this doesn't change the substance of the question, to which I do not know the answer.

Comment: I would expect it will be an update for the process, but just call them

Answer (score 1):

First, as @EugenMartynov suggests, it never hurts to ask. Having said that, and without actual experience with your situation:

#### Nobody assumes 1:1 relation between people and passports

Remember that a passport is merely an identification document. You are not your passport, and the passport attests to a proper unique identifier combination (e.g. name + birth date + birth place). So it does not seem reasonable that you should not be recognized as the same person because a different document attests to it.

My slightly-relevant experience with this situation is not Netherlands-related, but I once started some formal procedure vis-a-vis a consulate of Romania, being an Israeli citizen and using my passport. At some point I lost my passport, got it replaced, and simply used the new passport number in subsequent steps of this procedure. No questions were asked.

#### Use corroborating documents for the passport change

When continuing the process using your new process, always have a copy of your old passport handy (e.g. photocopied or scanned and printed). That will help if you do encounter trouble. Some states  may also issue confirmation that a passport has been invalidated or canceled; if that's the case in the state you live in, have that handy as well.